# Time Difference Formula in Calculated Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, 2016, date-time

How Can I achieve displaying time difference between two type "date and time " columns? I want to put the time difference in another column type "based upon calculation" of those two. I want to display difference of time between column "created" and column "closed"

EXAMPLE:

Start Time 1/24/2009 7:00 AM   End Time  1/24/2009 3:00 PM  Duration 8 hours

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following formula

```
=TEXT(Created-Closed,"h")
```

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

---

In case you need to show the exactly Hours and minutes, try this

```
=TEXT(Created-Closed,"hh:mm")
```

**[Output]**

[image]

---

Regarding Days and Hours and Minutes, try the below one

```
=DATEDIF(Created,Closed,"d") &" days .."& TEXT(Created-Closed,"hh:mm")
```

**[Output]**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, one more question. If I want to display it in days hours and minutes? Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, please check the new formula for your new request.

Comment: Very useful answers!

Comment: also, this doesn't seem to handle negative hours, for example if 'Start` equals `08/06/2020 08:00am` and Finish equals `08/06/2020 12:00am` and this formula is used `=TEXT(Finish-Start,"hh:mm")`, it returns `08:00` ... reversing the values in the formula returns the same result, ie `=TEXT(Start-Finish,"hh:mm")`